# How to create React Linkify with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to React and I need some help with how create React components in javascript.
I am trying to display any url that is in a text as hyperlink. And I am using React Linkify to do that. 
This is how it is done

```
<Linkify>
<p>The url to linkify website is http://www.google.com</p>
</Linkify>
```

But what am trying to do is creating all the html elements using javascript. Creating linkify using createElement isn't working

```
import Linkify from 'react-linkify';
showText()
{

   var conversationDiv = document.getElementById('conversation');

   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.appendChild(document.createTextNode("The url to google website is http://www.google.com"));     

   var linkify = document.createElement(Linkify);       
   linkify.appendChild(div); 

   var textPara = document.createElement("P");
   textPara .appendChild(linkify);
   conversationDiv.appendChild(textPara );

}

render() {
return (
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="conversation"></div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: React elements are not HTML elements, and you cannot treat them as such (although you can create them [without using JSX](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?presets=react&code_lz=DwEwlgbgBAxgNgQwM5IHIILYFMC8AiJACwHsAHUsAOwHMBaOMJAFzwD4AoKKYQgRlYDKJclWpQAMoyZQAZsQBOUAN6l5ZJADpKmLAF9gAej4cuwAK5wTXbg1YBJSswTV5mQ7c7XgtgOqEETEgAguTuYFamtgDyMBZmSGFWhhYchuAQrADc7EA)). Nor is it clear why anyone would *want* to do imperative DOM manipulations on them. What are you *really* trying to do here?

Comment: @JaredSmith I am trying to display the url as clickable hyperlink. Right now "The url to google website is http://www.google.com" is displayed as plain text and http://www.google.com is not a clickable url(hyperlink).